# Copy animation, or change parent

Tags: animation, constraints, parent

I have few objects. A Car1 and a Ball.
I need to animate the car and the ball so that they move together.
But at some point in time, the ball must move to another object (Car2) and move with it.
How to do that?
[image]
It's similar relationship parent - child, but with that the child change from time to time his parent.

Maby use constraints?

Comment: We usually use constraints for that, you can animate constraints' influence through time. Child Of for example.

Comment: it's a bit painful to set the Child Of constraint manually, but the Dynamic Parent addon can do it for you